# Why is input.autocomplete not working to clear previous history on my form? (HTML/JS)

Tags: javascript, html

```
const form = document.querySelector("#contact-form");
const feedback = document.querySelector(".feedback");
const patternName = /^[a-z A-Z]{3,25}$/;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const firstname = form.firstname.value;
if (patternName.test(firstname)) {
console.log(firstname);
feedback.textContent = "";
form.reset();
resetInputHistory();
} else {
console.log("invalid");
feedback.textContent =
  "Name field must not contain special characters or numbers and should not be less than three                letters.";
}


function resetInputHistory() {
const inputFields = form.querySelectorAll("input");
inputFields.forEach((input) => {
  input.autocomplete = false;
});
}
});
```

I have tried setting the input.autocomplete statement to both false and "off", yet field still shows all     the previous input history.

Comment: `autocomplete` is an HTML attribute. You must use `setAttribute` method.

Comment: Duplicate of [Dynamically dismiss autofill menu of <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584213/dynamically-dismiss-autofill-menu-of-input)

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to do the job either.  Set "input.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");" in place of "input.autocomplete = false;".

Comment: `autocomplete`  checkout this link. Hope this helps you. [HTML attribute: autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution without JavaScript**

you can see i use **autocomplete **(on)**** on my form and i also use **autocomplete (off)** on my email input tag inside the form. if you type any name in name input tag and submit after the reload the autocomplete work on that but if you try this for the email tag then autocomplete not work... so you can doing this from the HTML without using JavaScript....

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The autocomplete attribute</h1>

<p>Fill in and submit the form, then reload the page to see how autocomplete works.</p>
<p>Notice that autocomplete is "on" for the form, but "off" for the e-mail field!</p>

<form action="/action_page.php" autocomplete="on">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. Your suggestion work.  And do share why it doesn't work on an email field.

Comment: Autocomplete is not working on email input field because I have turned off autocomplete on input so it is not working. `<input type="email" id="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">` see this code carefully..

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you're already setting input.autocomplete to false, but that may not have the desired effect in all browsers.

try setting it to "off"

```
function resetInputHistory() {
  const inputFields = 
  form.querySelectorAll("input");
  inputFields.forEach((input) => {
  input.autocomplete = "off";
});}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
const form = document.querySelector("#contact-form");
const feedback = document.querySelector(".feedback");
const patternName = /^[a-zA-Z]{3,25}$/;

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const firstname = form.firstname.value.trim(); // Trim any leading/trailing whitespace
  
  if (patternName.test(firstname)) {
    console.log(firstname);
    feedback.textContent = "Form submitted successfully!";
    form.reset(); // Reset the form to clear input fields
  } else {
    console.log("invalid");
    feedback.textContent =
      "Name field must contain only letters and should be between 3 and 25 characters.";
  }
});
```